# "Could not retrieve product info" "Invalide product identifier" SwiftyStoreKit iOS Swift Xcode

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase, swiftystorekit

I am having a problem with the SwiftyStoreKit framework and I'm not even sure how to test to see if I have resolved the problem. When I use my sandbox account all of the purchases work great. But when I submit it to the App Store they reject it because they say they are getting a message that says, "Could not retrieve product info - Invalid product identifier: com.rrtenz.puzzlesfromsurvivor2.unlockAll".

I have included their screen shot below and the full text of there description of the problem.

[image]

> Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
>
> We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPad
>   running iOS on Wi-Fi.
>
> We received the attached error message when making any selection from
>   the store.
>
> Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please run your app on a device to identify any
>   issues, then revise and resubmit your app for review.
>
> If we misunderstood the intended behavior of your app, please reply to
>   this message in Resolution Center to provide information on how these
>   features were intended to work.
>
> For new apps, uninstall all previous versions of your app from a
>   device, then install and follow the steps to reproduce the issue. For
>   updates, install the new version as an update to the previous version,
>   then follow the steps to reproduce the issue.
>
> Resources
>
> For information about testing your app and preparing it for review,
>   please see Technical Note TN2431: App Testing Guide.
>
> For a networking overview, please review About Networking.

The product has been added to App Store Connect and the product identifiers match.

I don't know if this matters, but my app's Bundle Identifier is "com.rrTenz.**Puzzles-for-Survivors**", and my product identifiers are "com.rrtenz.**puzzlesfromsurvivor2**.xxxxx".

Here is my code:

AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    SwiftyStoreKit.completeTransactions(atomically: true) { purchases in
        for purchase in purchases {
            switch purchase.transaction.transactionState {
            case .purchased, .restored:
                if purchase.needsFinishTransaction {
                    // Deliver content from server, then:
                    SwiftyStoreKit.finishTransaction(purchase.transaction)
                }
            // Unlock content
            case .failed, .purchasing, .deferred:
                break // do nothing
            @unknown default:
                fatalError()
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Get Info Code:

```
func getInfo(purchase: RegisteredPurchase) {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.retrieveProductsInfo([bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue], completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationFinished()

        if let product = result.retrievedProducts.first {
            //handle info here
            [...]
        }else {
            //error alert
            [...]
        }
    })
}
```

Make Purchase Code:

```
func purchase(purchase: RegisteredPurchase) {
    NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationStarted()
    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct(bundleID + "." + purchase.rawValue, completion: {
        result in
        NetworkActivityIndicatorManager.NetworkOperationFinished()

        if case .success(let product) = result {
            //update purchase variables here
            [...]
        }
        //purchase complete alert
        [...]
    })
}
```

So as I mentioned before, I'm not sure how to debug this problem, because I can't even duplicate the behavior when I use my sandbox account. If anyone has any advise or can determine what I am doing wrong I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Not a fix to your problem, but I wouldn't display that alert. Any products that you can't retrieve at runtime simply shouldn't be shown for purchase.  You should get the price information from the `SKProduct` anyway, it should not be hard coded in your app. Are your in app purchases approved?

Comment: @Paulw11 I appreciate the recommendation. I will stop showing that can't be retrieved. 
All of my products that I have added are marked as "Cleared for Sale".

Comment: Do you have the same problem in a TestFlight build?  Is you IAP available in the US store?

Comment: I have not tried a TestFlight build. I will give that a try.
I don't believe the IAP is available in the US store because this is the first version of my app that I am trying to get released.

Comment: This is why the products (and their prices) should be displayed based on the information you get back from StoreKit; prices can change and vary by locale. The reviewer is almost certainly testing with a US based account. You can create a US sandbox user and test with that to see if you have a problem (and/or check in AppStore Connect to ensure that your IAP is available in the US region)

Comment: @Paulw11 I just used TestFlight to install the app and the purchase worked just fine - the purchase was completed successfully.
How do I verify which regions the IAP is available in?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193118/discussion-between-paulw11-and-ryan-tensmeyer).

Comment: Are your products in the 'Approved' stage? They will work for testing while in 'Ready to Submit' but must be approved before submitting to the App Store

Comment: @enc_life I am new to this process. I'm not sure how to get them to change to 'approved'. Right now they say 'waiting for review'. Is there something I need to do to get them to be 'approved' or will Apple just look at them when they get to them like they do with an app that is waiting for review?

Comment: In the "Prepare for Submission" page in App Store Connect there is a section to add In-App Purchases. You need to add them there so the reviewer knows to look at them with this version.